# JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'opera' of undefined or null reference

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

If I used `jquery-1.9.1.min.js` getting `JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'opera' of undefined or null reference` from `Jquery  Isotope v1.5.19` javascript file.

If I use `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js` JQuery. It is working properly and goes smooth. I all want to use latest of jQuery.

Any solution for this?

[image]

Comment: [`$.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) was removed in jQuery 1.9.

Comment: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed <= that's why you're getting an error

Comment: What is the solution for this? I am using modernizr-2.6.2.js. Still have same issue.

Comment: @James123: What is the problem you are trying to solve?  `$.browser` no longer exists.  You're going to need to check for the *exact* feature you want, not just the browser name.  Why do you want to check for Opera anyway?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to continue using old jQuery APIs, you need to load the jquery-migrate plugin before the jquery.1.9.1.js script.

E.g.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script>
```

[jquery-migrate download and read-me file](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate)

** Update:

Try to use Jquery Isotope v1.5.25. It was updated for Jquery 1.9 and doesn't have references to .browser plugin.

https://raw.github.com/desandro/isotope/master/jquery.isotope.js