# flot bar chart with long labels rendering issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot, bar-chart

i plotted a flot bar chat with long labels, and it came out ugly, i saw that it is possible to display the labels rotated like 90 degrees, but i tried with the following code without success. the javascript am using is

```
function onSuccess(series) {
            var tickLabels = [];
            var pieData= [];
            for (var i =0;i<series.length;i++){
                tickLabels.push([i,series[i][0]]);
            }
            var data = [series];
        var barArea = $("#barChart");  

        barArea.css("height", "400px");  
        barArea.css("width", "600px"); 


            $.plot( $("#barChart"), data, {
        series: {
         bars: {
            show:true,
            barWidth: 0.5,
            align: "center"
         },
            points: {
                show: true
            }
        },
        grid: {
            hoverable: true,
            clickable: true
        },
        xaxis: {
            labelWidth:12,
            labelAngle: 45,
            ticks: tickLabels
        }
        } );
```

**The chart**

[image]

does anyone know of any solution to this.

**Edit**

Is it possible to use legend in the bar chart and then pllace the legend below the bar char like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9LdKg/6/) or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9LdKg/8/) ?

Comment: is it possible to provide a example of your code and labelAngle should work .. in my code this worked
 `xaxis: {
                        min: -0.5,
                        max: 100,
                        ticks: xaxisTicks,
                        tickWidth: 0.5,
                        labelAngle: -90,
                        axisLabel: 'Test',
                        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 10,
                        axisLabelFontFamily: 'Arial',
                        axisLabelPadding: 8
                    },`

Comment: which code should i provide, and which flot version are you using?

Comment: am using 0.7 ..i want an example of how you tried in jsfiddle or jsbin..

Comment: I don't believe this feature exists in current flot versions.  It's supposed to be nailed down for the 0.9 release.  See lengthy discussion here: https://github.com/flot/flot/pull/15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Flot** doesn't support yet the *labelAngle* option. There are several proposals on the [Flot issue tracker](https://github.com/flot/flot/pull/15) but none of them yet accepted.

> i saw that it is possible to display the labels rotated like 90
>   degrees

What you saw (link please?) seems to be a forked version of Flot, like [this](https://raw.github.com/paradoxxxzero/flot/28f2377382b3af97c82cb3ebc081140b49fa9579/jquery.flot.js) one, which does support the *labelAngle* option.

Comment: A working jsFiddle example which uses the forked Flot version linked in my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/manishsp2008/vNSD8/ (I cannot add it to the answer because of SO 2 links restrictions for new users).

Comment: i  tried that example, but i get an error `Cannot read property 'opera' of undefined jquery.flot.js:1765` for the flot linked

Comment: The reason of that error is deprecated and removed $.browser in jQuery 1.9 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816712/javascript-runtime-error-unable-to-get-property-opera-of-undefined-or-null-re) You can modify the forked Flot, row #1765, replace if($.browser.opera) with if(navigator.userAgent.match(/opera/i)).

Comment: thanks very much, is it possible to wrap the labels into multiple line, at leans 2, instead of one long line

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Flot Tickrotor](https://github.com/markrcote/flot-tickrotor) plugin.  I'm not sure whether it still works with 0.7, though; it was recently updated to work with 0.8, and that might have broken backwards-compatibility.

We're right now working to integrate the plugin's functionality into 0.9.

I should point out that simply rotating the text will still look pretty weird; you can't avoid that without shortening the labels.

Comment: this plugin does not remove the original labels, instead is adss its own rotated labels and shift flot horizontal labels  down

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that; it's a bug that we fixed but haven't issued a minor release for yet.  If you grab the latest master off Github (https://github.com/flot/flot) it should work correctly.